# 3x 8GB RAM sticks installed but 1 stick is recognized as 512MB instead of 8GB

Tags: windows, memory

I recently installed some new RAM, but I am not sure why one of the sticks is read as 512MB when it should be 8GB.

I have tried reseating the RAM and resetting CMOS via battery and jumper but it still doesn't work. Is this because the RAM or mobo is faulty?

I am running 64-bit Windows 10, using G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series RAM.

[image: Speccy info 1/2]

[image: Speccy info 2/2]

Comment: Did you make sure your motherboard can support more than 16GB? Everything about that chip looks like it is bad. Try moving the memory in to different slots and see if the problem follows it. Try running the system with the one bad chip alone.

Comment: What happen when you exchange the RAM from slot#3 to slot #1?

Comment: Better answers could be given if you state the exact model of motherboard and/or computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this does probably mean "the RAM or mobo is faulty".  Or maybe just incompatible.  But the most likely cause is that the RAM is faulty.

Don't use this computer for anything important, like loading an operating system that interacts with data that you deem important.  A lot of software will randomize RAM locations due to some security benefit, so your impact may be random.  Your computer might work just fine, once, or it might cause invisible errors that affect some data and cause more problems down the road.

You've done well already (e.g., re-seating RAM).  The next recommended step is to see if the RAM stick passes a memory test (ideally in another computer, as if the problem follows the RAM stick and not the motherboard, that helps to verify the likely conclusion that the issue is with the RAM stick).

Note that although you've made great headway, and I'm saying the RAM stick is the most likely culprit, I wouldn't rule things out until confirming that problems follow the RAM stick, and not the motherboard.  (And if the problem is with the motherboard, maybe the issue is outdated firmware which could be fixed with a firmware update.)  So I would say that your troubleshooting efforts don't appear to be finalized quite yet.

Comment: I didn't have another computer to test but I took out every RAM stick and tried each one by itself. 2/3 worked and the one I suspected of being faulty failed to boot into POST.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening run and type msconfig and go to boot and advanced options and tick maximium memory and set your maximum ram.